# How to run a process after saving the data from a form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with an Interactive Grid in Apex 22.2. I modified the Add Row button to open a modal page that is a Form. This form contains two important fields "Created By" which is the App User and "Assigned To". I can fill in the fields and after clicking save the changes are correctly saved. What I want to achieve, as soon as the data is saved I want to run a function that checks if the "Created By" and "Assigned To" are different and if so it will send an email. I already have a function that sends an email that has been working for a few months. This is just a new email being sent on that specific condition.

I tried using dynamic action on the save button but I think it didn't do anything as the data wasn't saved when the dynamic action was triggered.

So the process would be "Add Row", modal dialog opens, users fill the form, users click save, the process checks if "Created By" and "Assigned To" are different and sends the email, the users close the modal dialog and go back to the interactive grid.

Something extra fancy would be to also close the dialog after saving it(if it was successful) and sending the email. But I am more than happy if it saves the data and sends the email.

Answer (score 0):

If

> users click save

is performed by a button on the (modal dialog) form page, then it - I presume - submits the page. Create a process which runs when that "Save" button is pressed and does something like

```
if :P1_CREATED_BY = :P1_ASSIGNED_TO then
   p_send_mail(...);
end if;
```

---

If that won't work for some reason, you could create a database trigger, e.g.

```
create or replace trigger trg_bi
  before insert on that_table
  for each row
begin
  if :new.created_by = :new.assigned_to then
     p_send_mail(...);
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: The Save button on the modal dialog indeed submits the page.  But the email needs to be sent after the data has been inserted and committed to the database. I can see in the process parameters that there is a Point: After Submit in the execution attribute. Does that guarantee that the information is saved in to the database and only then the process is run? If not I can go the route of the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Add another process after the modal dialog save process. Once the 1st process completes it will enters the 2nd process, on that add your email code to execute